# I'm having parallax / navigation choppiness issues - any way to make it more fluid? WordPress, Jupiter Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, parallax

The first thing you should know is that, I'm no expert at JavaScript...

I just finished working on a website at http://dev.munnrabot.com, customizing the hell out of it using the WordPress theme Jupiter.

As good as it looks and as happy as I am with it, there is still one major bug...the parallax scrolling and navigation is SLOW and not very responsive.

Before you tell me "well, you have lots of video's and sliders in there," I want to tell you that I took all of these out and the slowness still exists!

So it is not the sliders...

Is there anyone out there who can help me analyze the JavaScript and/or to help me implement a more fluid version of parallax?

I've worked tirelessly trying to figure out how to improve it, but nothing has worked, and now I'm desperate (sadly to say...)

Will be more than happy to compensate for services.

Thank!

Joseph Orr
joseph@joseph-orr.com

Comment: 'Parallax' JavaScript patterns bind many events and 'watches' for changes on many things at all times. Every time the window scrolls it has to re assess all of the parts - and not just every time it scrolls - every px it scrolls. Like you found, its not necessarily the sliders - (although they would contribute to the amount of memory needed and possibly to how clunky it would be) - It's that there are a lot of elements that have to be changed to position absolute and then have their positions animated based on a bunch of other elements positions. It's likely the best it will get. : (

Comment: You could try codersclan - or other paid help services - or maybe check out the codereview node of stackoverflow. This question will likely get downvoted because it doesn't show code - or clearly outline what you've tried and what happened and all the variations. Stackoverflow is for more specific questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: well even though i have to agree with @sheriffderek. a solution to your problem could become pretty complicated since its requiring a rewrite of how stuff is put together. it could be solved by doing some layer elevation through will-change and other tricks. also moving the animation to css instead of changing "height" and "padding" could benefit from it. you'd need to put lots of work into this. maybe ask your client if he likes modals.

Comment: Thanks guys! Sounds to be more complicated than I originally thought. I wonder if there is a way to remove the current parallax and implement a more reputable one? I believe the one that came with this theme is garbage (compared to one's I've seen)...

I understand the position: absolute answer - it is mostly the nav links, that when clicked, respond slowly. Especially if you click one right after the next, it takes 2-3 seconds to load one link, then almost 5+ seconds for the next...

The second best option for me is to remove parallax/scroll to position altogether, at least it wont be jumpy.

Comment: The only parallax site I've ever seen that seemed smooth enough that it wasn't a big negative, was the https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com site (which seems to be gone) ~ I bet it cost them 100 grand. I bet you'll save time by just designing a great looking site - and leaving out the effect. : )